# COG Driver not recognized in GDAL 3.2.0

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, anaconda, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I want to generate a Cloud Optimized Geotiff (COG) using Python (with Anaconda environment). I wanted to use GDAL 3.2.0 since it has a COG Built in Driver since 3.1. Initially I cannot update GDAL to 3.2.0, it just keep installing 2.4.4 I am not sure why. So I downloaded a 3.2.0 package here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal/files.

I installed it to my environment:

```
conda install gdal-3.2.0*.tar.bz2
```

Now it is now versioned 3.2.0 according to my

```
conda list
...
gdal            3.2.0            py37h6bca1a1_0    <unknown>
...
```

However when I try to use it, COG is still not recognized.

```
gdal_translate input.tif output.tif -of COG -co COMPRESS=LZW
```

It gives the error:

```
Output driver `COG' not recognised.
```

This is based on: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cog.html

My system is running on Debian 10.

Comment: Another test is to run `gdalinfo --format cog`. If the driver does not exist then there is some issue with the installation. It is still possible to create cloud optimized geotiffs with the old recipe https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/CloudOptimizedGeoTIFF.

Comment: `ERROR 1: --format option given with format 'cog', but that format not
recognised.  Use the --formats option to get a list of available formats,
and use the short code (i.e. GTiff or HFA) as the format identifier.`

Comment: Yeah I am trying now the old recipe.

Comment: And one more for making sure what GDAL version gets used `gdalinfo --version`.